# An equivalence class - $\mathbb{Z}/2011 \mathbb{Z} -\{ \overline{0}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the group $\mathbb{Z}/2011 \mathbb{Z}-{\overline{0}}$, find
$\overline{n}$ such that $\overline{n} \cdot \overline{27} =  \overline{12}$.

I think we have to find $n$ such that $n27 \equiv 12 \pmod {2011}$. Is there anyone that could help me find the value of $n$?

Comment: Why do some of the numbers have bars over them?

Comment: $\overline{n}$ is simply the equivalence class on $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2011 \mathbb{Z}-{\overline{0}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find the inverse $b$ of $27$ modulo $2011$.
Then $n\equiv 12b\pmod{2011}$. This is the "right" general way to do it.

Or else if you are in a hurry, we want to solve $9n\equiv 4\pmod{2011}$, or equivalently $9n\equiv -2007\pmod{2011}$. Divide by $9$. We get $n\equiv -223\pmod{2011}$. If you like, replace $-223$ by $2011-223$.

Comment: You are absolutly right! $ \overline{27}^{-1}=149 $, and $(149 \cdot 12)\cdot 27 \equiv 12 \pmod {2011}$

Comment: Had no choice, was smoking outside and had no paper to scribble on. So was forced to use a process that could be done in one's head.

Answer (score 0):

In the field $\mathbb F_{2011}$ we have the equation $27n=12$ which reduces to $3^2n=4$. On the other hand

(Little Fermat) $3^{2010}=3^2\cdot3^{2008}=1$ so $n=4\cdot3^{2008}$ and you have to reduce this quantity modulo 2011. For this you can use $$729=3^6<2011<3^7=2187$$